# How to divide a connected weighted graph to N semi-equal subgraphs

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I have a graph of many hundred nodes that are mainly connected with each other. I can do processing on entire graph but it really takes a lot of time, so I would like to divide it to smaller sub-graphs of approximately similar size.

With other words. I have a collection of aerial images and I do pairwise image matching on all of them. As a result I get a set of matches for each pair (pixel from first image matched with pixel on second image). Number of matches is considered as weight of this (undirected) edge. These edges then form a graph mentioned above.

I'm not so familiar with graph theory (as it is a very broad topic). **What is the best algorithm for this job?**

Thank you.

**Edit**:
This problem has a perfect analogy which I think is easier to understand. Imagine you have a set of people and their connections/friendships, like I social network. Each friendship has a numeric value/weight representing how good friends they are. So in a large group of people I want to get `k` most interconnected sub-groups .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the problem you're describing is almost certainly NP-hard. From a graph perspective, you have a graph where each edge has a weight on it. You're trying to split the graph into relatively equal pieces while cutting the lowest total cost of edges cut. This problem is called the maximum k-cut problem and is NP-hard. If you introduce the constraint that you also want to try to make the pieces roughly even in size, you have the balanced k-cut problem, which is also NP-hard.

The good news is that there are nice approximation algorithms for these problems, so if you're looking for solutions that are just "good enough," then you can probably find a library somewhere that implements them. There are also other techniques like spectral clustering which work well in practice and are really fast, but which don't have any guarantees on how well they'll do.

Comment: I also added another analogy for easier understanding, if that somehow affects your answer. Thank you for your help.